# Extrinsic curvature of plane curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, general-relativity

I asked this question first on physics forum, but there is no response. I post it here and hope someone can help me out.

I know two kinds formulas to calculate extrinsic curvature. But I found they do not match.

One is from "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach"$K=\frac{d\phi}{ds}$ where $\Delta \phi$is the change in direction and $Δs$ is the change in length. For parametric form curve $(x(t),y(t))$ the extrinsic curvature is given by
$$ K=\frac{x'y''−x''y'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}} $$
where $′≡\frac{d}{dt}$

The extrinsic curvature formula in general relativity from "Eric Possion, A Relativist's Toolkit" is given by $K=∇_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}$. For a plane curve $(x(t),y(t))$ in flat space, the outgoing unit normal vector is $(n^x,n^y)=(\frac{y′}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}},\frac{-x′}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}})$, and the extrinsic curvature is (**my interpretation of Possion's formula**)
$$K=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}n^x+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}n^y=\frac{1}{x'}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}n^x+\frac{1}{y'}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}n^y=2\frac{x'y''−x''y'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}$$

Is there anything wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean $(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}$ in the denominators.  As written, the first formula computes the curvature of a circle of radius $a$ to be $a$, and it should be $\frac{1}{a}$.  But I don't know how to resolve the factor of two discrepancy.

Comment: yes,sorry for such a typo,Thank you

Comment: Something about $K = \nabla_{\alpha} n^{\alpha}$ is a little odd: The normal vector is defined only along a curve, but the sum over $\alpha$ is taken over extrinsic coordinates. Does Poisson give the curvature with the factor of $2$, or is that your interpretation of $K = \nabla_{\alpha} n^{\alpha}$...?

Comment: It is my interpretation. There must be something wrong here.

Comment: Usually a sum of the type $\nabla_{\alpha} n^{\alpha}$ extends over _intrinsic_ coordinates; for a curve, that would be one term. Since the "unnormalized normal" $N = (-y', x')$ is a quarter-turn rotation of the velocity $T = (x', y')$, the rate of change of $N$ (as an angular velocity with respect to a curve parameter) must agree with the rate of change of $T$ (the ordinary curvature). :) To get a number rather than a vector as the derivative of $N$, you want to view $N$ as taking values in a circle, i.e., to write $n = (\cos\theta(t), \sin\theta(t))$ and to calculate $d\theta/ds$.